# Delete a file from a Facebook group

Tags: facebook-groups

I'm the administrator for a small private group on Facebook. There are some files that we've shared and they are conveniently listed under "Files" in our group.

However, one of our members has uploaded several different revisions of a file, and we only want to keep the latest one.

The file listing under "Files" only offers a link to download the file. There is no link or other doodad to click to delete the file. As the Owner of the group, I'd expect that *I* at least would have access to delete a file.

How can I delete a shared file from a Facebook Group?

Comment: Try the fist answer of [this](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=4580885049518) or the second answer of [this](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=10103897180121674). Please note I have not tested any of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the way to delete a file is a little counter-intuitive. You actually have to delete the file from the original post that put in there.

1. Find the post where the file was attached
2. Open up the message menu (down-pointing arrow in upper right)
3. Choose "Delete File"
    [image: Message menu with "Delete File" highlighted]

Answer (score 0):

Find the File tab on the left side menu in your group. Click on it. Find the file that you want to remove. Click on the post link next to your profile pic. View original post. Click the 3 dots on the top right side of the post. From the drop down menu, click delete.

Comment: Uh...that's basically what the accepted answer says.