# How to update a file in a Facebook Group

Tags: facebook-groups

I've uploaded a PDF document to a Facebook Group that I am a member of. I want to upload a newer version of the file without having the old one there. Can I do it without deleting the old one and posting a new message?

Answer (score 3):

This seems a little counter-intuitive, but you can add a revision to the original post.

1. Find the post where you added the file
2. Click the <kbd>Upload Revision</kbd> button
   [image: post file menu]
3. You'll get information on the file, including all revisions. Click the "Upload New Version" button
   [image: Upload New Version]
4. Select your file and upload

If you need to get rid of a revision, follow the advice in [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/90978/354), except choose "Delete file revision" from the post menu.

Newer versions of Facebook have moved the link. Go to the `Files` section of the group and click on the menu (three vertical dots) next to the file to find "upload revision".

Comment: THERE IS NO 'upload revision' anymore -- this is NO LONGER WORKING, and it's annoying because I want to keep all of the comments on the original post. I have to delete it in order to get a revised doc uploaded while avoiding confusion between the 2! (oct 2018)

Comment: I've left this here for your convenience, ale.  Please flag it as no longer needed if/when you update the answer.

Comment: @john: Following ale's advice (near the end of the answer), I was able to find the "upload revision" option. It's "hidden" in the "Files" section of Groups. Thanks, ale, it worked well!

Comment: this does not seem to be possible as of 2022.